# PHP bulk uploading a csv file

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
$data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $data['mainpage']='masterorder';
        $data['mode']='masterorders';
        $this->load->view('includes/mainpage', $data);
    } else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            $this->db->trans_begin();
            $successflag=true;
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                //                  


                $order = array(
                    'sheet_type'=>$this->input->post('sheet_type'),
                    'order_id'=>$row['OrderId'], 
                    'order_name'=>$row['OrderName'],
                    'department'=>$row['Department'],
                    'gender'=>$row['Gender'],
                    'maturity'=>$row['Maturity'],
                    'group_name'=>$row['GroupName'],
                'cat_id'=>$row['Category'],
                'sub_cat_id'=>$row['Sub-category'],

                );
                //$this->db->trans_begin();
                $query = $this->db->query("select count(*) cnt from order_master where order_id='{$order['order_id']}'");
                $row = $query->first_row();
                if(trim($order['order_id'])!="" && $row->cnt==0 )
                //if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
                {

                    $this->masterorder_model->order($order);                     
                }
                else if (  $row->cnt>0)
                {
                   $successflag=false;
                   break;
                }


            }


            if(!$successflag)
            {
                $this->db->trans_rollback();
                $this->flash->success('<h4>Duplicate Values Found.</h4>');
            }
            else
            {
                 $this->db->trans_commit();
                $this->flash->success('<h4>Csv Data Imported Successfully.</h4>');
            }
            redirect(base_url().'masterorder/index');

        }
        else
        $data['error'] = "Error occured";
        $data['mainpage']='masterorder';
        $data['mode']='masterorders';
        $this->load->view('includes/mainpage', $data);
    }
}
```

This is my code while bulkuploading a csv file iam getting the validation as duplicate values found if there is any duplicate id in the same how can i get that duplicate id i should show that id also can any one give me idea.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Its kind of difficult to understand exactly what your problem is. Can you provide a bit more detail regarding what your exact problem is?

Comment: iam uploading a csv file into database if in that file there are any unique values it is returning as duplicate values found but i should get the message as well as the id which is duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method will be very slow if you have a lot of data to upload. You'd do better to make more use of MySQL's capabilities. Here's some pseudo code to get you started:

```
Upload CSV file to server

Create temporary table in MySQL database for data to be imported

Load data to temporary table with LOAD DATA INFILE

Find duplicates with an inner join
   SELECT `id` from `current_table` c inner join `temp_table` t on c.id = t.id;

If number_of_rows_returned = 0 {
   merge data with Insert...SELECT
} else {
   create report from data selected above
}
DROP temporary table
```